# Select by Attributes - If string has a letter

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, sql, query

I'm running ArcMap 10.1.

I'm using a File Geodatabase.

I have a string coordinate field that I want to clean and some records have letters in it (mostly 'N' or 'E' or 'n' or 'e' e.g. '6213210N' or 'N6584312' but also some refer to map a grid reference e.g 'm29').

I want to select the records that have a letter regardless of it's position or what letter.

Why wouldn't this work?

```
UPPER("CoordinateField") LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

As far as I can see it works in for similar solutions but not in ArcGIS. As seen **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)**.

Am I using incorrect notation for something stored in a File Geodatabase?

Hoping someone can shed some light on this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of the query is usually dictated by the underlying database, and file geodatabases do not support '%[A-Z]%' style LIKE predicates.

But, if it is just letters that have multiple cases, you should be able to compare the output of UPPER and LOWER functions for changes.  If there aren't any, then there aren't any characters that have case.  This will not detect special characters like ! @ #.  I am sure this will also fail if there are letters from some other non-English alphabets.

```
UPPER("CoordinateField") <> "CoordinateField" OR LOWER("CoordinateField") <> "CoordinateField"
```

Comment: +1 - seems more flexible than my workaround

Comment: Great answer - Its OK about special characters as I only have to deal with spaces and '.'

Answer (score 2):

The **Select By Attribute Help button** displays text that includes:

"To query file-based data, including file geodatabases, coverages, shapefiles, INFO tables, dBASE tables, and CAD and VPF data, you use the ArcGIS SQL dialect that supports a **subset of SQL capabilities**." (my bolding)

It also refers to the **[SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000)** which makes no mention of square brackets being available for anything other than delimiting field names from Personal Geodatabases.

As a workaround you may want to add a flag field that you can set to perhaps 1 or 0 depending on whether your desired selection criteria is met and then use Python syntax in the Field Calculator to parse your strings before selecting using the flag.

Alternatively you could also just use something like:

```
UPPER("CoordinateField") LIKE '%N%' OR UPPER("CoordinateField") LIKE '%E%'
```

(expanded to all 26 letters of the alphabet if you wished).

Comment: Looks like I've been skim reading that page. The 2nd solution is the one I'm using for the moment. Thanks for the reply.